# PHP - Autoloading a class in to my view

Tags: php

### The goal

Use helpers in my views without `include` or `require` a  class.

### The problem

My views are using some helpers to perform multiple necessities. What I have now, for instance:

```
App\Helpers\Words::Has('orange', $cocktail); // returns 'true'
```

But I don't need to use "`App\Helpers`" anymore. I just want to use `Words::Has[...]`. If I omit the `App/Helpers`, this happens:

> Warning: require_once(.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Autoload.php on line 10

### What do I already tried

In the controller that render the view, I already tried to put this in the header's scope:

```
use App\Helpers\Words;
```

But unfortunately, no success — nothing happens.

Can someone give me an idea?

### The autoloader.php

```
<?php
spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $classMatrix = explode('\\', $class);
    array_shift($classMatrix);

    $finalClass = implode('/', $classMatrix);

    require_once $finalClass . '.php';
});
```

**I don't want to load the helper through the view.**

Comment: Try using absolute paths. Your autoloader may try to locate `Helpers\Words.php` from the wrong folder

Comment: Can you suggest me a way to use absolute paths? I mean, I can't understand how can I apply one in that context.

Answer (score 1):

This is your `Autoloader` and you are using `Words::Has()` and class name `Words` is being passed in the `$class` variable of your autoload function parameter. So, lets see what's going on :

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

    $classMatrix = explode('\\', $class); // = $classMatrix = explode('\\', 'Words');
    // Result is $classMatrix = Array ( [0] => Words )

    array_shift($classMatrix); // removes and returns first element from the array
   // Result is $classMatrix = Array ( )

    $finalClass = implode('/', $classMatrix); // $finalClass is empty

    require_once $finalClass . '.php'; // = require_once '.php';
});
```

If you want, you may register a separate `autoloader` for helper

```
spl_autoload_register('load_helper');
function load_helper($class) {
    require_once 'app/helpers/' . $class . '.php';
}
```

So, you can now use

```
Words::Has(...);
```

Comment: I can see the error now. Anyway, I think that is unfeasible to my case to create a separate autoloader — and what if there's one more entity than helper? By the way, thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome @GuilhermeOderdenge! This is a common practice (I've seen) to use multiple autoloaders (`app/controllers`, `app/models`, `app/views`) but you may also add include path or whatever suits your need. BTW, you may use [this](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md#splclassloader-implementation).